# Deploying CSI sidecars and CSI driver on Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I am novice in using CSI in Kubernetes. 
I am trying to deploy CSI driver & sidecars to existing Kubernetes cluster. I am following this link 
  https://github.com/kubernetes-csi/csi-driver-host-path

The error which I got after executing deploy.sh is

```
> $ ./deploy.sh
applying RBAC rules
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-csi/external-provisioner/v1.6.0/deploy/kubernetes/rbac.yaml
serviceaccount/csi-provisioner created
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/external-provisioner-runner created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/csi-provisioner-role created
role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/external-provisioner-cfg created
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/csi-provisioner-role-cfg created
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-csi/external-attacher/v3.0.0-rc1/deploy/kubernetes/rbac.yaml
serviceaccount/csi-attacher created
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/external-attacher-runner created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/csi-attacher-role created
role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/external-attacher-cfg created
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/csi-attacher-role-cfg created
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-csi/external-snapshotter/v2.1.0/deploy/kubernetes/csi-snapshotter/rbac-csi-snapshotter.yaml
serviceaccount/csi-snapshotter created
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/external-snapshotter-runner created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/csi-snapshotter-role created
role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/external-snapshotter-leaderelection created
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/external-snapshotter-leaderelection created
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-csi/external-resizer/v0.5.0/deploy/kubernetes/rbac.yaml
serviceaccount/csi-resizer created
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/external-resizer-runner created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/csi-resizer-role created
role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/external-resizer-cfg created
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/csi-resizer-role-cfg created
deploying hostpath components
   ./hostpath/csi-hostpath-attacher.yaml
        using           image: quay.io/k8scsi/csi-attacher:v3.0.0-rc1
service/csi-hostpath-attacher created
statefulset.apps/csi-hostpath-attacher created
   ./hostpath/csi-hostpath-driverinfo.yaml
error: unable to recognize "STDIN": no matches for kind "CSIDriver" in version "storage.k8s.io/v1"
modified version of ./hostpath/csi-hostpath-driverinfo.yaml:
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: CSIDriver
metadata:
  name: hostpath.csi.k8s.io
spec:
  # Supports persistent and ephemeral inline volumes.
  volumeLifecycleModes:
  - Persistent
  - Ephemeral
  # To determine at runtime which mode a volume uses, pod info and its
  # "csi.storage.k8s.io/ephemeral" entry are needed.
  podInfoOnMount: true
```

Please suggest a way to fix this.

Comment: Can you attach the result of `$ kubectl version --short` to question body? and where you created the cluster?

Comment: Hello.. I have a similar problem as the OP and i have created a Issues on the project in gitlab here https://github.com/kubernetes-csi/csi-driver-host-path/issues/187 - i tested it on 15,16 and 17 and have the same issue..
@KamolHasan - i provided my kubectl version --short output in the issue on GITLAB